Group action on cohomology is trivial
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a normal subgroup. Let $M$ be $H-$module.
I want to check $G/H$ acts on $H^1(H,M)$ by $(\bar{\sigma}*X)(g):=\sigma X({\sigma}^{-1}g\sigma)$ where $X $ is cocycle in $H^1(H,M)$ and $\bar{\sigma}\in G/H$ is the image of $\sigma\in G$ in $G/H$.
That is, I want to prove the following proposition.

$\sigma_1≡\sigma_2 \text{mod}H\implies
(\bar{\sigma_1}*X)(g)=(\bar{\sigma_2}*X)(g)$.

I calculate $\sigma_1X({\sigma_1}^{-1}g\sigma_1)-\sigma_2X({\sigma_2}^{-1}g\sigma_2)$.
$\sigma_1X({\sigma_1}^{-1}g\sigma_1)=\sigma_1(X({\sigma_1}^{-1})+{\sigma_1}^{-1}X(g\sigma_1)))=X(\sigma_1)+X(g)+gX(\sigma_1)$.
Thus,$\sigma_1X({\sigma_1}^{-1}g\sigma_1)-\sigma_2X({\sigma_2}^{-1}g\sigma_2)=X(\sigma_1)-X(\sigma_2)+gX(\sigma_1)-gX(\sigma_2).$
This is coboundary, so we gain the result.
But I feel weird.

Where did I used the condition $\sigma_1≡\sigma_2 \text{mod}H$ ?

I am not sure whether I am unconsciously using this condition somewhere in the proof or if the proof itself is incorrect. My question is, could you please tell me where this condition should be applied?

The group $H^1(G,M)$ has nothing to do with $H$. So what is $H$?!

@Claudius Thank you, it was $H^1(H,M)$.

So you want to show that the action of $G$ on $H^1(H,M)$ factors through $G/H$?

@Claudius Yes, you are correct.

In that case, it suffices to show that $H$ acts trivially on $H^1(H,M)$, which simplifies the computation.

@Claudius Is your notation 'factor through' weaker than the condition what I asked in this question ? It is proved here , https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212636/the-term-h1n-ag-n-in-the-inflation-restriction-exact-sequence(see Ehud Meir's comments)

It is equivalent. Could you design your post in such a way that it becomes clear (a) what is given/known and (b) what you want to prove? If you say at the beginning that $G/H$ acts on $H^1(H,M)$, then there is nothing to prove, right?

@Claudius thank you. I edited my question.

Next, it is unclear what precisely you mean by $X$ (and especially, what $X(g)$ is for $g\in G$).

@Claudius Thank you for your clealification, i edited.

Again, you used $X(\sigma_1)$ in your proof with $\sigma_1 \in G$. How do you make sense of this if $X$ is a cocycle of $H$?

@Claudius Yes, indeed, this is very strange and confusing. The precise definition of the action on the cocycle seems to have become dubious. It appears to be the crux of my question.

@Claudius G acts on cohomology, and I can prove H acts trivially on this action. From this, why can we conclude the proposition in my question？Also, I can't quite understand why it doesn't work well to try to prove it in the form of a proposition in my question (it can't be expanded following the cocycle condition).

By “factoring through $G/H$” I mean the following: A $G$-action on $H^1(G,M)$ (or any vector space/module) is the same as a group homomorphism $\rho\colon G \to \mathrm{Aut}(H^1(H,M))$. Now, $H$ acts trivially, which means that $H$ is contained in the kernel of $\rho$. By the homomorphism theorem, $\rho$ factors through a group homomorphism $G/H \to \mathrm{Aut}(H^1(H,M))$.

@Claudius Thank you very much. Do you think it very possible that we can prove proposition in my question directly usinf cocycle condition？

You were right to be suspicious of not having used the congruence mod $H$ anywhere, and in fact your proof is not valid. The coycle $X$ is a function on $H$ satisfying $X(h_1h_2) = h_1X(h_2) + X(h_1)$ (the "cocycle condition") when $h_1$ and $h_2$ belong to $H$.
You have tried to decompose
$X(\sigma_1^{-1} g \sigma_1)$ using the cocycle condition, but this is not valid because $\sigma_1$ is not necessarily an element of $H$. (Note that $g$ should be an element of $H$ -- I would recommend writing it with a lowercase $h$ instead.)
What your proof actually shows is: if $X$ is the restriction of a cocycle from $G$, then any two elements of $G$ act on it trivially. Indeed, this is true (the restriction map lands in the subgroup of $H^1(H, M)$ which is fixed by the action of $G/H$), but it's not what you're trying to show.
It remains to give a proof of the original desired result; namely, that $H$ acts trivially under the purported action of $G$ on $H^1(H, M)$. There is no need to appeal to $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ -- it's enough to show that any $\sigma$ in $H$ itself acts like the identity.
So the thing to check is that if $\sigma$ and $h$ are in $H$, then
$$
\sigma X(\sigma^{-1} h \sigma)
$$
differs from $X(h)$ by a coboundary, for any cocycle $X$. Now using the cocycle condition is valid (because everything is in $H$). Using a similar computation to the one you have already done, we see that this expression is
$$
\sigma \sigma^{-1} X(h \sigma) + \sigma X(\sigma^{-1}) = X(h \sigma) - X(\sigma) = hX(\sigma) + X(h) - X(\sigma).
$$
Writing $m = X(\sigma)$, this differs from the original cocycle $h \mapsto X(h)$ by the coboundary $h \mapsto hm - m$, so we are done.
